# How to calculate monthly sum from the entries for each date in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

[image]

I have colums for my workout logging:

Date
Running (minutes)
Pushups
Pullups
Crunches

and the rest of my workout entries.

I insert my achievements each day.

How can I script Excel to automatically generate a sum of my achievements throughout the month?

Month
Running (hours) (example : 1800 minutes in a whole month and I'll convert that in hours, but that's easy)

And the rest of the entries.

So when I do this for the next 3 months, I'll have my monthly log for those 3 months too?

Update: I have tried calculating the amount of cells having the same month, then outputting a sum of the number of minutes ran, but failed at doing so. :/

Comment: You should create a _pivot table_ and group the dates by month.

Comment: What you you tried so far? Excel has lots of great tools specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can see where this one would get a little dicey. There is a great function that will work perfectly for this one. It's a little advanced, but I'll explain it. In Cell I3 enter: `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A3:A100)=3)*(B3:B100))`

What this will do is sum up everything in `B3:B100` that has a date in March (month 3) in `A3:A100`. This works much like `sumif`, but it will allow you to do fancier tests on your range before summing up.

If the sheet grows and you wish to extend the function to take the Year into account then: `sumproduct((month(A3:A100)=3)*(YEAR(A3:A100)=2014)*(B3*B100))` In other words, you can add more conditions to your test just by sticking them into a set of parentheses and adding them into the list with an asterisk.

Comment: I up-vote this solution because it does not require an extra column to maintain. However, many users will be better of adding this extra column and using `sumif`, like I describe, because this is _more comprehensible._

Answer (score -1):

## Use `=sumif()` referring to a hidden column with start of month

First add a column to calculate the (first of) the month for each date, then use that in an a =`=sumif()` statement

[image]

### Formulas in row 2:

- B2 : `=A2+1-DAY(A2)`
- I2 : `01/03/2016`
- J3 : `=SUMIF($B:$B,$I2,C:C)/1440`
- K3 : `=SUMIF($B:$B,$I2,D:D)`
- L3 : `=SUMIF($B:$B,$I2,E:E)`
- M3 : `=SUMIF($B:$B,$I2,F:F)`
- N3 : `=SUMIF($B:$B,$I2,G:G)`

### To hide column B :

right click above it to get the context menu